# Atomでタブバーの幅を変えるにはどうしたら良いですか？

Tags: atom-editor

Atomでタブバーの幅を変えるにはどうしたら良いですか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

英語で使ってるので、コマンドの正確な名前は違うかもしれませんが

- 設定 > テーマ（左リスト内） > （歯車ボタン） > タブサイズ

から変えられます。

もっと自由に変えたい場合はスタイルシート（設定を開くコマンドの近くに開くコマンドがあります）で

```
.tab-bar {
  font-size: 21px; // 文字サイズ

  .tab {
    min-width: 10em !important; // 最小タブ幅
    max-width: 19em !important; // 最大タブ幅

    //　ネタ
    color: green !important; // 文字色
    .title::before {
      content: " ";
    }
    .title::after {
      content: " ";
    }
  }
}
```

の様にすると、以下のようになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>などから開発者ツールを起動し、タブバーの部分にどんなCSSが適用されているか確認してください。

そのあと<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>からSettingsを開き、"Open Config Folder" から設定ファイルのあるフォルダにし、スタイルシートを編集すればよいです。

たとえば次のCSSはタブバーの最小幅を設定します。

```
.tab-bar {
  .tab {
    min-width: 100px;
  }
}
```

他には`active`(今見ているタブにつくクラス)などのクラスや、`max-width`、`flex`などのプロパティがあります。Atomのバージョンやテーマによってここらへんは変わりうるので、適宜設定してください。